# I need to reset or deselect a group of radio buttons in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to reset or deselect a group of radio buttons. How do I do that ?

Comment: If you have found a solution, you should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted once you are able. It's ok to answer your own question (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the selected property to true but not false.   so add a "dummy" radio button to the group (no need to add it to the display list) and use it:

```
var rbDummy:RadioButton=new RadioButton();
rbDummy.group = rb1.group;


function reStart(evt:MouseEvent):void {
     rbDummy.selected = true;

}
```

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/436875

Answer (score 1):

You can make additional unvisible radiobutton and check it programaticcaly.

Comment: Thanks,but i want to reset both radio btns, i don't want to unvisible.

Comment: i found Solution


import fl.controls.RadioButtonGroup

var rg:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup("aaa");
r1.group = rg;
r2.group = rg;

_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,reset);

function reset(e:MouseEvent) { 
 var tempBtn:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
 tempBtn.group = rg;
 tempBtn.selected = true;
 rg.removeRadioButton(tempBtn)
}

Comment: it can be done by RadioButtonGroup's Selection Property see ans for eg see ans

Answer (score 0):

You can set its selection property to null

```
radioButtonGroup.selection = null

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="radioButtonGroup" />
    <mx:VBox>


    <mx:RadioButton id="a"  label="A" groupName="radioButtonGroup"/>
    <mx:RadioButton id="b" label="B" groupName="radioButtonGroup"/>
    <mx:RadioButton id="c" label="C" groupName="radioButtonGroup"/>

    <mx:Button id="btn" label="Unselect" click="{radioButtonGroup.selection = null}"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

hopes that helps

Comment: i found Solution

 import fl.controls.RadioButtonGroup

var rg:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup("aaa");
r1.group = rg;
r2.group = rg;
_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,reset);
function reset(e:MouseEvent) { 
 var tempBtn:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
 tempBtn.group = rg;
 tempBtn.selected = true;
 rg.removeRadioButton(tempBtn)
}

Comment: A line is in AS3 radioButtonGroup.selection = null, in your reset function just try this "rg.selection = null;" hopefully it will works and is proper way