# how to deselect all Radio Button in Radio ButtonGroup on button click in flash as3?

Tags: flash

how to deselect all Radio Button in Radio Button Group on button click in flash as3?

Comment: There is answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962666/i-need-to-reset-or-deselect-a-group-of-radio-buttons-in-as3/39564699#39564699

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop on all button and unselect in a nutsheel you have to do something like this

```
var nbChildren = myDisplayObjectContainer.numchildren;

for(var i:int = 0 ; i < nbChildren ; i++){
 if( myDisplayObjectContainer.getChildAt(i) is RadioButton )
 {
  var radioButton:RadioButton = myDisplayObjectContainer.getChildAt(i); as RadioButton;
  radioButton.select = false;
 }
}
```

Of course you have to use correct type instead of : RadioButton and your select/unselect method